# Access Google Spreadsheets API on Safari

Tags: google-sheets

After I made my Google Spreadsheet public I can access the JSON file from the Chrome browser (Stealth Mode) but on Safari it prompts you login to Google accounts. Since the spreadsheet is public it should be able to access from any browser? or I am missing something.

Here is the endpoint:

> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sxocf4BllxZhWDrHlJQXOFWYwWmHPmfxvn9qqyV8JJE/6/public/values?alt=json-in-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

Instead of sharing with Public or with anyone with the link, publish your spreadsheet

## Explanation

From https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

> Note: Retrieving a feed without authentication is only supported for published spreadsheets.

To publish a spreadsheet follow the instructions of [Publish and embed Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en)